# Notating three simultaneous notes of different durations for piano

Tags: notation

On the same staff, how do I notate three simultaneous notes of different duration?  For example, half notes on middle C and the C above and four eighth notes on the G inbetween

Answer (score 9):

Welcome to MP&T.

You can do it like either of these:

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  I had tried the first, but I like the second better.

Comment: I used to do this with a common vertical line.

Comment: @Joshua You naughty person, you :-)

Answer (score 4):

From what you say it sounds like you need two voices.  The middle Cs plus the octave can be joined as one voice, and the Gs would be a second voice.  You would have one stem going down and the other going up.

Comment: Jomiddnz's answer is the same as mine. (+1) As (s)he says, you need two voices.

Comment: Thanks.  I was trying to avoid the stems up running into the stems down. Looks like I can get close.